# Autocorrelation function of discrete time sequence

Tags: signal, signal-processing, matrix

Say you have 2 discrete information sources each one being represented by a Gaussian random variable.
[image]

This is the idea. Say I want to find the correlation of the 2 to know whether they are stationary. This is the discrete formula for correlation:
[image]
How would this look in matrix multiplication terms. Using the process X(t) and the formula Rxy could you construct a circulant matrix with one of the sequences and multiply each row by the other non shifted sequence? Would you have a circulant matrix with cos2pif as weights and the vector with sine weights? then would you have to divide the product of the multiplication by the multiplication of the variance for each of the random variables to normalize it?

Trying to visualize what the correlation matrix would be. Thanks.

Comment: Err, if \$ \mu = 0, \text{var} = \sigma^2 \$ applies to both \$X,Y\$, aren't they stationary by definition?

Comment: Oh yea i think you are right but I would still want the values to know how strongly correlated.

Comment: Then see [this](https://stackabuse.com/calculating-pearson-correlation-coefficient-in-python-with-numpy/)

Comment: That page is great thank you.